# Find Command Exclude Hidden files when using empty flag

Tags: bash, macos, find

I am looking for a way to use the find command to tell if a folder has no files in it. I have tried using the `-empty` flag, but since I am on macOS the system files the OS places in the directory such as `.DS_Store` cause find to not consider the directory empty. I have tried telling find to ignore `.DS_Store` but it still considers the directory not empty because that file is present.

Is there a way to have find exclude certain files from what it considers `-empty`? Also is there a way to have find return a list of directories with no visible files?

Comment: This is a good question, but would probably be more appropriate on [apple.se] or [linux.se].

Comment: But I suspect there's no way to get `find` to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can use `-execdir` to run a script in each directory and be more selective about emptiness.

Comment: I thought of several ways to do it with a script, but it just seems like overkill and the wrong way to do it. My thought is that there has to be some way to tell ``find`` to just ignore hidden files.

Comment: The `-empty` predicate for a directory test very specifically that the directory has no entries other than a possible `.` and `..`.  For a regular file, it checks that the size is equal to 0.  There is no other logic/configuration for that test.
 https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/pred.c?id=75dd3bbfe2c6be00f75b7d3211504d9641099086#n317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-empty` [predicate](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/pred.c?id=75dd3bbfe2c6be00f75b7d3211504d9641099086#n317) is rather simple, it's true for a directory if it has any entries other than `.` or `..`.

Kind of an ugly solution, but you can use `-exec` to run another `find` in each directory which will implement your criteria for deciding what directories you want to include.

Below:

- the outer `find` will execute `sh -c` for each directory in `/starting/point`
- `sh` will execute another `find` with different criteria.
- the inner `find` will print the first match and then quit
- `read` will consume the output (if any) of the inner `find`. `read` will have an exit status of 0 only if the inner `find` printed at least one line,  non-zero otherwise
- if there was no output from the inner `find`, the outer `find`'s `-exec` predicate will evaluate to false
- since `-exec` is followed by `-o`, the following `-print` action will be executed only for those directories which do not match the inner `find`'s criteria

```bash
find /starting/point \
  -type d \( \
    -exec sh -c \
      'find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name ".*" -print -quit | read' \
      sh {} \; \
    -o -print \
  \)
```

Comment: I tried this, but on Big Sur it throws the following error `bash: line 0: read: -N: invalid option
read: usage: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]
`

Comment: After going to the man pages for Read on Mac looks like there is no ``-N`` in the read included with macOS so that won't work. It does look like ``-n`` works though

Comment: Good point, I'll change it. (TBH neither option is necessary, it just makes the shell exit as soon as it reads a character, rather than reading the whole filename)

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the 'find FOLDER -empty' is somewhat tricky.  It will consider FOLDER empty even if it contains files, as long as these are empty.

Maybe not exactly what was asked, but I prefer the brute force approach if I want to avoid a no-match error on using FOLDER/*.  In tcsh:

```
ls -d FOLDER/* >& /dev/null
if !($status) COMMANDS FOLDER/* ...
```

A variation of this might be usable here (like also using
ls -d FOLDER/.* | wc -l
and drawing the desired conclusions from the combined results).